# How do I handle AWS s3 returning file/object names with the + character in place of a space?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3

I just ran into the issue with S3 returning filenames with a `+` character instead of a space. I'm using Lambda to get an S3 object that was created, so the filename in the `response` object is showing as `thisfilename+word.txt` when the original filename on S3 was `thisfilename word.txt`.

I know I could parse the filename and replace all `+` characters and delete them, but I can't guarantee that the files won't have that character in their filenames...

Is there a proper way to handle this?

Comment: Can you show the code you are using? Are you using boto? Listing keys in a bucket takes an optional argument called `encoding` which can be either `None` or `"url"`. If it's set to `url` spaces will be replaced with `+`, so try setting it to `None`.

Comment: Not using any encoding. Lambda receives a dictionary of the event, structured like the example at the bottom of this page: https://marnee.silvrback.com/aws-lambda-and-s3-a-quick-and-dirty-tutorial so by default, I'm receiving this key with + signs

Comment: Per the documentation page, it seems to be URL encoded http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html

Comment: You will need to urldecode it then. I'm not immediately familiar with how to do that in python, but I'm sure it is easy.